# tnsping not working for //SERVER:PORT/SID format

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, tnsnames, tns, tnsping

This Works

> app @ [server: /u01/home/apli/app/trx/appS_Apps/appS_Apps/logs ]
>   :/>tnsping app_test
>
> TNS Ping Utility for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 10.2.0.4.0 -
>   Production on 08-SEP-2015 01:01:57
>
> Copyright (c) 1997,  2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Used parameter files:
>   /u01/home/app/oracle/product/10.2/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
>
> Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias Attempting to contact
>   (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (Host =
>   monger) (Port = 1531))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = app_test))) OK (10
>   msec)

But this does not. Why?

> app @ [server: /u01/home/apli/app/trx/appS_Apps/appS_Apps/logs ]
>   :/>tnsping //monger:1531/app_test
>
> TNS Ping Utility for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 10.2.0.4.0 -
>   Production on 08-SEP-2015 00:59:16
>
> Copyright (c) 1997,  2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Used parameter files:
>   /u01/home/app/oracle/product/10.2/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
>
> TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name

app @ [server: /u01/home/apli/app/trx/appS_Apps/appS_Apps/logs ] :/>ping monger
PING monger.corp.com: (10.140.2.74): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.140.2.74: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=0 ms
64 bytes from 10.140.2.74: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0 ms
64 bytes from 10.140.2.74: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0 ms
^C
----monger.corp.com PING Statistics----
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0/0/0 ms

> app @ [server: /u01/home/apli/app/trx/appS_Apps/appS_Apps/logs ]
>   :/>tnsping //10.140.2.74:1531/app_test
>
> TNS Ping Utility for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 10.2.0.4.0 -
>   Production on 08-SEP-2015 00:59:40
>
> Copyright (c) 1997,  2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Used parameter files:
>   /u01/home/app/oracle/product/10.2/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
>
> TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name app @ [server:
>   /u01/home/apli/app/trx/appS_Apps/appS_Apps/logs ] :/>

Answer (score 0):

`tnsping` is used to test yout network configuration via `tnsnames.ora`. I doesn't make sense to call it with ips and ports. See also here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/connect.htm#NETAG357

Answer (score 0):

On Windows with Oracle 12, it can be used as wanted.

```
tnsping host:port/servicename
```

The command line forms an EZConnect Oracle SQL connection string. Note that no leading slashes used in the system name devhost.corp.company.com.

```
PS C:\Users\user1> tnsping devhost.corp.company.com:12021/devdb 

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 14-NOV-2022 10:29:25

Copyright (c) 1997, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\Oracle\product\12.2.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Used EZCONNECT adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=devdb))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.50.206.21)(PORT=12021)))
OK (70 msec)
```